# Explodir linhas de um textarea e separá-los por virgulas

Tags: php

Opa,

Preciso capturar o texto do textarea, separá-lo por linhas e então dar um explode e separá-lo pelas virgulas.

```
        $lines = explode("\n", $respostas);
        $i = 0;
        if ( !empty($lines) )
        {
            foreach ($lines as $line)
            {
                $i++;
                    //Adiciona Respostas
                    foreach($respostas as $key)
                    {   
                        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO respostas
                            VALUES (
                                NULL, $i, '$key'
                        )");
                    }
                    //Adiciona Respostas

            }
        }
```

Em que no insert do mysql, preciso salvar o conteúdo ($key) a linha ($i), mas, está duplicando os inserts de acordo com a quantidade de linhas.

Exemplo do textarea:

```
teste, teste1, teste2
teste3, teste4
```

Comment: O que tem no $respostas?

Comment: Conteúdo do textarea: 

`
teste, teste1, teste2
teste3, teste4
 `

Deve ser separado as palavras separadas por virgula e por linha

Comment: entendi, ele vem dessa forma então

Comment: No Caso @AndréBaill, aqui não exibe a formatação de exibição, adicionei o conteúdo exemplo do textarea na pergunta

Comment: me diga uma coisa, todos serão separados por virgula já? e outra coisa... o objetivo é inserir estes registros no banco de dados?

Comment: Sim, o usuário já digitará as palavras separando-as com a virgula, inclusive com a separação entre linhas e será para cadastro no banco

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43688/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-snniffer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz aqui e imagino que seja isso que você quer, veja se atende:

```
$respostas = "teste, teste1, teste2
        teste3, teste4";
        $lines = explode("\n", $respostas);
        $i = 0;
        if ( !empty($lines) )
        {
            $aWords = [];
            foreach($lines as $line){
                $aWords[] = explode(',', $line);
            }
            //Adiciona Respostas
            foreach($aWords as $key => $aWord2)
            {   
                $linha = ($key+1);
                foreach($aWord2 as $word){
                    $word = trim($word);
                    $query = "INSERT INTO respostas VALUES (NULL, $linha, '{$word}')\n";
                    echo nl2br($query);
                    //$sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                }
            }
        }
```

Resultado ficou assim:

```
INSERT INTO respostas VALUES (NULL, 1, 'teste')
INSERT INTO respostas VALUES (NULL, 1, 'teste1')
INSERT INTO respostas VALUES (NULL, 1, 'teste2')
INSERT INTO respostas VALUES (NULL, 2, 'teste3')
INSERT INTO respostas VALUES (NULL, 2, 'teste4')
```

Descomente a linha do $sql para inserir na base ou altere conforme necessidades extras.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Boa tarde Fabil, seu script funcionou perfeitamente, mas, ao upar para o server online, está me retornando `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' `, isso no local onde está a linha `$aWords = [];`. Há algo que possa ser feito para contornar? Abraço

Comment: substitua as chaves [] por:
array();
ficando:
$aWords = array();